# Проверка переменных на совпадение

Tags: python, переменные, проверка

Как сделать что-бы если переменная a = или < переменной b было написано неправильно а если a > b код продолжил исполнятся. При вводе.    a <= b выдаёт ошибку[image: Ошибка исполнения кода]

Comment: Попробуйте сами. Попытку добавьте в вопрос. Пока не понятно что вам не понятно.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Пишем в python код:

```
import sys
a = <число>   
b = <тоже число>
if a == b:
    pass
elif a > b:
    pass
else:
    sys.exit()
```

Также я заметил, ты в строке if a <= b пропустил двойную точку - if a <= b:

Comment: Сейчас проверю сработает

Comment: Я заметил, ты в строке if a <= b пропустил двойную точку - if a <= b:

Comment: Спасибо я думал в чём ошибка а тут в :

Comment: @GobGobo, об этом надо явно в ответе указать

Comment: `pip install sys` - это не нужно делать, sys - это стандартный модуль Python, его не нужно и не получится так установить, он всегда есть. Вообще не понятно при чем тут `sys.exit()`. Проблема только в отсутствующем двоеточии.